# DataGridView Current Cell border Highlight

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using a datagridview with the selectionmode as full row select

I am not able to find how to darken the border of the current cell.

Can any body please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Handle DataGridView MouseDown event

```
private void dataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
     cell = //..get from info
     cell.AdjustCellBorderStyle(..
}
```

This is just example from head, hope that works.